# QgsFeatureRequest() with a string search within QGIS3 Processing Script

Tags: qgis-3, pyqgis-3, qgsfeaturerequest

I'm trying to select features using a string comparison within my script using a `QgsFeatureRequest()` and `getFeatures()`

```
roadsRequest = QgsFeatureRequest()
roadsExpression = str(roadsIDField[0]) + ' LIKE ' +  str(featIDUnique)
feedback.pushInfo(roadsExpression)
```

For reference then, the roadsExpression looks like the below or I have tried using an " = " operator too:

> identifier LIKE 534553B5-9A71-4DE2-B8C2-56B0B31D5EB2

I've then set the filter expression of the `QgsFeatureRequest()` object and passed attempted to get features as below and `getFeatures()` should return a `QgsFeatureIterator`:

```
roadsRequest.setFilterExpression(roadsExpression)
roadsFeatures = roadsSource.getFeatures(roadsRequest)
```

Now, I've brought `roadsSource` in as a `parameterAsSource()` to provide a `QgsProcessingFeatureSource()` object and I therefore get a valid `QgsFeatureIterator` object in `roadsFeatures` but this is empty.

However, I am unable to edit a `QgsProcessingFeatureSource` object therefore I tried bringing `roadsSource` in using `parameterAsVectorLayer()` to provide a `QgsVectorLayer()` object that I can edit. However when I use `getFeatures(roadsRequest)` on this vector layer object, I get an invalid feature iterator.

I think I am doing something wrong with how I've built my request using the strings but I don't know what as everything is compiling and running without any errors, I'm just not getting the results out that I expect.

Comment: You need to wrap the string in your expression in single quotes: `"{0} LIKE '{1}'".format(str(roadsIDField[0]), str(featIDUnique))`